# How to change Hapi response code in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I am implementing an app using Hapi with TypeScript.
I saw [this article](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/hapi-how-to-set-response-status-code) about how to change the code, but I have issues with it from TS.

```
reply(err).code(401);
```

TypeScript compiler complains here that `.code()` function is unresolved.

`reply` is `IReply` and I use this type definition file https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/hapi/hapi.d.ts